# Building a sequential string into an array (quickly)

Tags: arrays, powershell

I've written the following code to build an array with sequential strings.
It works like I expect, but I wish it ran quicker.  Is there a more efficient way to produce my desired results in PowerShell?

I'm very new to PowerShell and appreciate your coaching.

```
$MIN = 1
$MAX = 20000
$ARRAY = @()
$PREFIX = "AA"

$startDTM = (Get-Date) # Start time
FOR ($i=$MIN; $i -le $MAX; $i++)
{
   If ($i -gt 0 -and $i -lt 10) {
     $ARRAY = $ARRAY + ($PREFIX+"00000"+$i)
   }
   If ($i -gt 9 -and $i -lt 100) {
     $ARRAY = $ARRAY + ($PREFIX+"0000"+$i)
   }
   If ($i -gt 99 -and $i -lt 1000) {
     $ARRAY = $ARRAY + ($PREFIX+"000"+$i)
   }
   If ($i -gt 999 -and $i -lt 10000) {
     $ARRAY = $ARRAY + ($PREFIX+"00"+$i)
   }
   If ($i -gt 9999 -and $i -lt 100000) {
     $ARRAY = $ARRAY + ($PREFIX+"0"+$i)
   }
   If ($i -gt 99999 -and $i -lt 1000000) {
     $ARRAY = $ARRAY + ($PREFIX+$i)
   }
}
$endDTM = (Get-Date) #End Time
"Elapsed Time: $(($endDTM-$startDTM).totalseconds) seconds"
$ARRAY.count  #How many loaded.
```

Example of `$ARRAY`:

```
AA000001
AA000002
...
AA019999
AA020000
```

Comment: Never use array concatenation - the `+` operator - in a loop as it recreates the array each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following one-liner tooked **0.4911672** seconds (your example **12.9638944** seonds). Results are the same. It uses the format string with decimal specifier to ensure there are 6 digits and just store the result in the array:

```
$MIN = 1
$MAX = 20000
$PREFIX = "AA"

$ARRAY = $MIN .. $MAX | % { "$PREFIX{0:D6}" -f $_ }
```

You can further improove the performance by using a while loop (thanks 4c74356b41 for mentioning that):

```
# ....
$array = while ($MIN -le $MAX) 
{
   "$PREFIX{0:D6}" -f $MIN++
}
```

This tooked **0.0970327** seconds on my computer.

Comment: Funniest thing is, I've posted completely broken code (thanks to a typo) :)

Comment: Yeah, but you mentioned the thing with the while loop. Piping the result of the range operator to the foreach-object cmdlet is so tempting because it looks very nice but obviously isn't performant...